# How to get the list of agents in the block Queue in Anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

How to get the list of agents in the block Queue in Anylogic?
In my model each agent A located in the Queue at the moment is a container with some agents B.
I have to count agents B. To do this I'm trying to get a list of agents A in the Queue:

```
int countB = 0;
for( AgentA agentA : Queue.contents()) {
    countB = countB + agentA.contents().size();
}
traceln(countB);
```

but `Queue.contents()` returns me an empty list.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.contents()`.

The queue name is enough i.e.

```
for( AgentA agentA : Queue )
```

Comment: I tried this. But in this case I get an error: `can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`

Comment: Is your queue name `Queue`? I've used this syntax in every model I've built and it always works... Maybe we don't have enough details about your model.